# iAd interstitialAd display problems

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial

I made an application (Ios) containing insterstitials pubs. When I test with the version of development,  I see display advertising(pub who told me that I am connected to iAd). 
I put it on the apple store, and there appears no pub. I tested on 4 devices and displays none of the pub ...

Here's the code:

```
ADInterstitialAd * pub;
BOOL requestingAd;   

-(void)showFullScreenAd {
        NSLog(@"%d",requestingAd);
        //Check if already requesting ad
        pub = nil;
        requestingAd = NO;
            pub = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
            pub.delegate = self;
            self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
            [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
            NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
            requestingAd = YES;


    }

    -(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        pub = nil;
        requestingAd = NO;
        NSLog(@"interstitialAd didFailWithERROR");
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    -(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidLOAD");
        if (interstitialAd != nil && pub != nil && requestingAd == YES) {
            [pub presentFromViewController:self];
            NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidPRESENT");
        }//end if
    }

    -(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
        pub = nil;
        requestingAd = NO;
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidUNLOAD");
    }

    -(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
        pub = nil;
        requestingAd = NO;
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");
    }
```

Then after I called "showFullScreenAd".
Normally the code works well. On the simulator and on my iPad, it works very well.

Do you know the source of this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help